# C++ MultiLine #if

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I've been trying to google this for a while now but I can't seem to be able to find any clear answer if it can be done at all.

I wanted to know if it's possible to do a MultiLine #if statement in C++ in a similar way to this type of if

```
if (
   1 == 1 ||
   2 == 2 ||
   3 == 3
) {
   cout << "True\n";
}
```

I was hoping for something along the lines of (which I know is hopelessly wrong)

```
#if
   1 == 1 ||
   2 == 2 ||
   3 == 3
#then
   cout << "True\n";
#else
   cout << "False\n";
#endif
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#if \
   1 == 1 || \
   2 == 2 || \
   3 == 3
   cout << "True\n";
#else
   cout << "False\n";
#endif
```

Backslash-newline combinations are stripped very early in preprocessing, even before tokenizing the input. You can use this to spread preprocessor directives across multiple physical lines.

Heck, you could theoretically even do

```
#i\
f 1 == 1 |\
| 2 == 2 || 3 =\
= 3
```

but then your colleagues might get upset with you.

Comment: Ok wow I never even knew about continuation lines so this is pretty amazing news to me <3

Comment: they should be getting upset at you with a multi line #if in the first place

Comment: I need the multi line #if though because the terminal is really small (old tech, long story) and it's just wrapping the code making a big fat mess

Comment: @melpomene I don't suppose there's like an anti continuation line? to imitate a line break without a line break?

Comment: @TheLovelySausage You mean, to put multiple preprocessor directives in a single line? (I can't imagine any other context where a line break is required.) No, there's no such thing.

Comment: @melpomene for example #ifdef VAR; myVar = "VAR"; #endif, but if it doesn't exist that's totally kwl, I don't need it I'm just being a curious pain in the ass

Answer (score 6):

Yes. With continuation lines:

```
#if \
   1 == 1 || \
   2 == 2 || \
   3 == 3
   cout << "True\n";
#else
   cout << "False\n";
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper way of usage is that below. Each preprocesing macro can be written in multiple lines using `\` on the end of current line. There is no `#then` keyword in cpp :)

```cpp
    #if \
       1 == 1 || \
       2 == 2 || \
       3 == 3
       cout << "True\n";
    #else
       cout << "False\n";
    #endif
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the answer for this would be using character escaping for end of line '\'

```
 #if \
   1 == 1 || \
   2 == 2 || \
   3 == 3
   void foo(){}
#else
   void bar(){}
#endif
```